# Cannot import function that is part of Sklearn?

Tags: python, module, scikit-learn, package, cross-validation

I am trying to use `RepeatedStratifiedKFold` via `from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedStratifiedKFold`.  I can see that this functionality is implemented in Sklearn, by looking on the website [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/model_selection/__init__.py).

I have recently done `pip install -U scikit-learn`, and have version 0.18.2 installed.  When I look in `C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\model_selection\__init__.py`, however, there is no mention of `RepeatedStratifiedKFold` (see below).

Does anyone know why this function listed as part of the Sklearn code, but does not appear when updating the Sklearn package?

Additionally, how do I access this function?

```
from ._split import BaseCrossValidator
from ._split import KFold
from ._split import GroupKFold
from ._split import StratifiedKFold
from ._split import TimeSeriesSplit
from ._split import LeaveOneGroupOut
from ._split import LeaveOneOut
from ._split import LeavePGroupsOut
from ._split import LeavePOut
from ._split import ShuffleSplit
from ._split import GroupShuffleSplit
from ._split import StratifiedShuffleSplit
from ._split import PredefinedSplit
from ._split import train_test_split
from ._split import check_cv

from ._validation import cross_val_score
from ._validation import cross_val_predict
from ._validation import learning_curve
from ._validation import permutation_test_score
from ._validation import validation_curve

from ._search import GridSearchCV
from ._search import RandomizedSearchCV
from ._search import ParameterGrid
from ._search import ParameterSampler
from ._search import fit_grid_point

__all__ = ('BaseCrossValidator',
       'GridSearchCV',
       'TimeSeriesSplit',
       'KFold',
       'GroupKFold',
       'GroupShuffleSplit',
       'LeaveOneGroupOut',
       'LeaveOneOut',
       'LeavePGroupsOut',
       'LeavePOut',
       'ParameterGrid',
       'ParameterSampler',
       'PredefinedSplit',
       'RandomizedSearchCV',
       'ShuffleSplit',
       'StratifiedKFold',
       'StratifiedShuffleSplit',
       'check_cv',
       'cross_val_predict',
       'cross_val_score',
       'fit_grid_point',
       'learning_curve',
       'permutation_test_score',
       'train_test_split',
       'validation_curve')
```

Comment: Check pip freeze

Comment: It seems this was added in 0.19, which has not been made available to pip yet. If you truly need it, you can install from source by running `pip install -U git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn`.

Comment: Ah, thank you @JonasAdler, a follow up question.  How were you able to tell?  On the page that I linked to, the branch being worked on was `master`, so I incorrectly assumed it had already been added. :/

Comment: I Googled "RepeatedStratifiedKFold 0.18" and got only bad results, so i guessed as much. No magic sadly.

Comment: Also, master branch is currently active branch on which the work is being done. Once its been added to pip it will be renamed to a version like 0.18.0, or 0.18.1 etc..

Comment: There is no `RepeatedStratifiedKFold` in https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.18.X/sklearn/model_selection/__init__.py